# javafx tableview column resizing issue

Tags: java, javafx

I am using Sceenbuilder to design the GUI. In the TableView i have 9 columns. All columns except one same width is fine. Here is the screenshot from sceenbuilder:
[image]

I only want the column "serial" smaller in width. So i set resize policy to CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY. And disable only resizing only for "serial" column and set it to a fixed size(such as 50).

In sceenbuilder preview it is working fine but when i compile the code i get a empty column at the end like this:
[image]

Only after resizing any column using mouse  it gets desired width automatically. My question is Why should it first require to drag any column using the mouse? This is what i don't want!.

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue on my program, and I fixed it this way.

Leave the `TableView` as `CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY`. Then, on the `TableColumn` you want a certain `width`, set the `max` , `min`, and `pref` size to the same size. This way, it will be no bigger and no smaller than your size.

> Edit 1:

After playing around with it, I've determined you only NEED to set the `max width` of your `TableColumn` to whatever size you want it to be, as this will allocate the appropriate space on the table header, my example below still works though.

Example below:

> Environment.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.91" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <center>
      <TableView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="First Name" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Last Name" />
            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Email Address" />
            <TableColumn maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0" text="Age" />
            <TableColumn maxWidth="50.0" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0" text="Height" />
        </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

> Main. In my example, the `fxml` file is in a directory named `fxml`. Please adjust code for this.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fxml/Environment.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,800);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```